# How to Create Online Skype Meetings for Outlook Appointments using excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, skype-for-business, lync-2013

I am trying to automate the process of creating meeting invites in outlook. In this regard, I have the macro to create appointments in outlook from data in excel sheet.

The challenge is, I have to convert them into “Online Skype for business meetings”.

Basically a code to do the clicking of button “Skype meeting” have to be done. Request you to help me out!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the idea behind to do some appointments in excel?

Comment: We have the meeting cadence with all the supporting details stored in an excel sheet. So automating this process.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a real method to do this unfortunately.
My current workaround is to add a button "Skype Meeting" to the Quick Access Toolbar and activate it via SendKeys % (Alt) and SendKeys